# Show Dynamic Image into InfoWinow to each marker in Android Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker, infowindow

I want to show a dynamic image into info window. I already can get the images from my webservice, however, just the last image stored in my db show's to all markers I've added into my google map. How I add each image to each marker separately?

Here is my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                e = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    LatLng Location = new LatLng(e.getDouble("latitude"), e.getDouble("longitude"));
                    byte[] decodedByteSmallBitmap = Base64.decode(e.getString("foto"), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    final Bitmap smallBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteSmallBitmap , 0, decodedByteSmallBitmap .length);
                    byte[] decodedByteBigBitmap= Base64.decode(e.getString("foto_grande"), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    final Bitmap bigBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteBigBitmap, 0, decodedByteBigBitmap.length);

                    markerOptions = createMarker();

                    // Setting click event handler for InfoWIndow
                    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                            // Remove the marker
                            marker.remove();
                        }
                    });


                    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                            LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                            info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                            TextView title =  new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                            title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                            image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                            image.setImageBitmap(bigBitmap);

                            TextView snippet = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                            snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                            snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                            info.addView(title);
                            info.addView(snippet);
                            info.addView(image);
                            return info;
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your code:

You are populating the info window in info window adapter which is a property of `mMap`.

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() ...
```

This means that for every marker of `mMap` you will be running the same `getInfoContents` method.

At each iteration you change the info window adapter to a new one and this means that at the end your `mMap`'s info window adapter will be set to the last info window adapter created in the loop.

This is your `getInfoContents` method of info window adapter:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView title =  new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    title.setText(marker.getTitle());

    image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    image.setImageBitmap(bigBitmap);

    TextView snippet = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    info.addView(title);
    info.addView(snippet);
    info.addView(image);
    return info;
}
```

For the title you used the function `marker.getTitle()` and for the snippet you used `marker.getSnippet()` but for the image you have just given the parameter `bigBitmap`. This means that for every marker your info window will be using the same bitmap: last `bigBitmap`. So you need to have a method like `marker.getBitmap()` which returns the bitmap associated with the marker. I think you can achieve this by changing the `createMarker` function.

You can see an example of population of image here (in function: render):
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java#L117